# How to build and run a Python command line application?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm trying to build a simple command line application using Python. At the moment, I call my application in Windows PowerShell, for instance, as:

```
python myprog.py --input_file "test_file.json" --init_size 10
```

My objective is to let anyone call the application as:

```
myprog --input_file test_file.json  --init_size 10
```

What should my approach be?

Comment: You could write a batch file (myprog.bat) that hides the Python call. Otherwise you could build an executable (PyInstaller)

Comment: For use of command-line parameters see https://avidpython.com/python-basics/command-line-argument-using-sys-argv-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setuptools` library to help package your application into a wheel (installable module, like from PyPi), then add the `scripts` argument to specify how you want to run it from the command line:

```py
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['bin/funniest-joke'],
    ...
)
```

> When we install the package, setuptools will copy the script to our PATH and make it available for general use

You can find more information [here](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) about how to incorporate this functionality.